# C# namespace not generated because of using reflection (no type instantiated)

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces, autofac, assemblies

I got the following issue:

I have a project / namespace *ViewModels* that containing several viewmodel classes described by a custom attribute that holds an interface type like:

```
[Register(typeof(IMyViewModel))]
public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel
```

In **another** project I use *Reflection* to get all ViewModel-Types with this specific attribute and register them to an *Autofac Inversion of Control* - Container like

```
builder.RegisterType(type).As(interfaceType);
```

So far, it works correctly and the classes are registered as their interface types.

But now, if i call the *Container.Resolve* function of *Autofac*, there is an IO-Error saying some dlls have not been found. It looks like:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyProject/files/.__override__/de-CH/Autofac.resources.dll'
```

The issue seems to be **because none of the types declared in the *ViewModel* project are instantiated anywhere directly**. My program works like a charm if I create an empty class in the ViewModel project and simply instantiate it anywhere like

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1()
```

So my question is:

**Is there a better way to make sure an assembly exists even if there is no direct instantiation of any type in it?**

thank you very much :)

Comment: I have a hard time to understand how the error message is related to the missing assembly.

Comment: Does the required file exist ? Could you share the code doing the assembly scanning and registration ? Could you also share the full stack trace of the error message ?